# How can I add page numbers to PDFKit generated PDFs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I have multiple pages generated using PDFKit.  How can I add page numbers to the bottom?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to specify a footer like this:

```
kit = PDFKit.new(your_html_content_for_pdf, :footer_html => "#{path_to_a_footer_html_file}")
```

then in the footer file have this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function subst() {
        var vars={};
        var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
        var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
        for(var i in x) {
          var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
          for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0;" onload="subst();">
    Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

elements of classes 'frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection' will get substituted with the appropriate data

Comment: hthanks, i wrapped the footer in <div id="footer"> and then styled in with kit.stylesheets << pdf.css ... but it didn't work...is there something special about the way the footer is treated?

Comment: hello, I think I have a slight problem: I mass-merge multiple contacts of my letters into a single document...it may be a two page letter but I have 15 of them, so it shows page numbers as 1...31....can I change that?

Answer (score 15):

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    header_right: "Page [page] of [toPage]"
  }
end

kit = PDFKit.new(body_html)
```

Read all detailed documentation here:
http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html

PDFKit is just a wrap up for wkhtmltopdf application that is written in C.

Comment: Works great, seems easier than the script option.  Only thing is is should be underscored ie header_right

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Please note the commented what @riley mentioned. Needs to be header_right. footer_right also works.

Comment: @hendrik This solution will not work if you use `footer_html` option.

Answer (score 10):

I did page number with PDFKit, just by adding this:

```
%meta{:name => 'pdfkit-footer_right', :content => "[page]"}
```

in my haml file, in my RoR project.

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason, ( perhaps because I'm using slim ) - I have to use single quotes around the content, instead of double quotes - or else it attempts to escape the brackets and raw text "[page]" shows up, so try single quotes if you run into this issue with your pages.